# C# How to redirect assembly loading using application config file

Tags: c#, winforms, versioning, gac, app-config

I have an assembly with few versions registered in the GAC. Now, I want one of my clients which uses this assembly (version 1.3) to point to the newest version (1.4) without opening the source and recompiling the client.
I saw an article demonstrating a technique for doing so using the application config file (winform application)

here is the config file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:asm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<runtime>
<asm:assemblyBinding>
  <!-- one dependentAssembly per unique assembly name -->
  <asm:dependentAssembly>
    <asm:assemblyIdentity
       name="MyFacade"
       publicKeyToken="c9c18e16df1654e0" />
    <!-- one bindingRedirect per redirection -->
    <asm:bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.3.0.0"
                  newVersion="1.4.0.0" />
  </asm:dependentAssembly>
</asm:assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, there is a binding redirect from version `1.3.0.0` to `1.4.0.0` for assembly named `MyFacade`.

Now, there's only a Minor issue with this approach. It doesn't work  :)

I'm sure it's something with my code.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Adi Barda

Comment: Use fuslogvw.exe to see what the CLR is considering.

Answer (score 3):

first, **[this is the best source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=VS.90).aspx)** I've found about this subject. There are some differences, for example, they are not using the `asm:` namespace, and also, you might want to disable the publisher policy by adding `<publisherPolicy apply="no" />` as described in the article.

In a previous project we did, we needed even more control, so we needed to **catch the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx)** and route to any assembly we wanted. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx) you can find more informations about the concept. You'd have to manipulate your app once, though.